# Force Exim to use ipv4 ip

Tags: email, centos, smtp, sendmail

I have an unmanaged VPS that runs CentOS 7 Minimal. I have installed Exim for sending emails. My main server IP is IPv4 and I have an additional IPv6 address.

Exim uses the IPv6 address to send emails. I want to overwrite this and use the IPv4 main server address. I added the `interface` line to the exim.conf:

```
remote_smtp:
   driver = smtp
   interface = x.x.x.x
```

And then restarted Exim but no matter what, it uses the IPv6 one. I thought that Exim is ignoring the config file but that's not the case as if I enter wrong IP format for interface and try sendmail, I get wrong IP format while sending email.

I tried adding `disable_ipv6 = true` to the end of exim.conf but when I saved and restarted Exim, I got the following error when running Sendmail: "Option disable_ipv6 unknown"

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, moved the disable_ipv6 to the begining of the config file and it was solved

```
root@hostname/etc/exim4 # service exim4 restart
root@hostname/etc/exim4 # exim -bP disable_ipv6
disable_ipv6
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make IPv4 only transport work (with having IPv6 enabled or even other transports using it).
You have to specify "`ipv4_only = true`" at the router section where you "call" the transport with the "interface" with IPv4 specified, eg:

```
dnslookup_IPv4:
  driver = dnslookup
  ipv4_only = true
  transport = remote_smtp
  ...
```